# Landscape orientation for iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4, orientation, landscape

Frustrated by how simple this should be...

I'm trying to add landscape support to an existing iPad app of mine. Do I actually have to create a completely new view controller for landscape mode? (surely not as that is a complete pain!)? Or can I use the existing view controllers and design for landscape and portrait? The simulated metrics thing doesn't work because whenever I make changes in a view controller in landscape mode and switch back to portrait it messes everything up! I know how to switch the view to landscape programmatically, this is (at least i think) an 'interface builder' sort of issue.

Why is this so difficult to do/hard to find!? Might be worth mentioning I'm using Xcode 4.2 with storyboards rather than separate xibs. Surely I don't have to use a separate view and segues because I really can't be bothered wasting my time with that.

Any help would be nice! Thanks

Comment: Elaborate on how switching back to portrait "messes everything up". Are you manually moving your views around? How are you autoresizing masks set up? This would all be helpful information.

Comment: yeah i'm manually changing the views. I'm going to have a look at autoresizing masks because I've never heard of it! Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch for -willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: and change the frame of your interface elements when the rotation changes.